# How to round up number in ng-bind

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

Here is the code I have

```
 <td><span ng-bind="'$' + (o.Price | number : 2)"></span></td>
```

In the example above, the result is 68.74.

In order to make this number meaningful, I must round it up to 69

Comment: `round(68.74)` use the round function

Comment: round not work on ng-bind

Answer (score 0):

You should use Pipe To help you with that

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

    @Pipe({name: 'roundUp'})
    export class RoundPipe {
      transform (input:number) {
        return Math.round(input);
      }
    }
```

so the code should be like that

```
 <td><span ng-bind="'$' + (o.Price | roundUp)"></span></td>
```